# CR, LF and CRLF characters in a String

Tags: javascript, special-characters, line-breaks

Is it safe to assume that a string will at any time only have either CR, LF or CRLF for a line break?

I want to write a logic to replace all the LF characters with CRLF characters in JavaScript but I have to this doubt.

I was thinking I can find all the LF (\n), check if it doesn't have CR(\r) before it and then replace the \n with \r\n.

If anyone has done this, please suggest what is the best way to do it?

Comment: in which context are you using Javascript here ? for "code" only, without specific need to write a file readable by the operating system, only `\n` should be enough, that would be the standard for new lines used by Javascript engines.

Comment: @Pac0 I want to replace any LF characters with CRLF inputted in a textarea. This is because I have a limit on number of characters for the textarea. The system which stores the value from this textarea automatically replaces LF with CRLF. So if a user is using a Mac or copy pastes a string typed on a Mac (meaning it has only LF), the front-end will not consider CR which will be added later in the limit which cause the problem later when value is being saved in the database.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the `\r` symbol standalone is never used to make a line-break. It can be `\n` or `\n\r`. In this case, you can use a regular expression `/\n\r?/g` to replace all possible linebreaks:

```
var someString = "kappa\npride\n\rgreyFace"
var lfcrRegexp = /\n\r?/g
var result = someString.replace(lfcrRegexp, "whatever") // => kappawhateverpridewhatevergreyFace
```

Comment: \r was used by old versions of MacOS, but not recently

Comment: @Pac0 Well, then, the regexp will be `/(\n|\r|\n\r)/g`

Comment: All the occurrences above of `\n\r` are not in correct order. For the CRLF the order should be `\r\n`, not vice versa. Because `\r` is CR and `\n` is LF.

Answer (score -1):

Use can use replace method it'll automatically check if match string is there then replace that with an argument.

```
   var data = "LFSingh";
   data = data.replace("LF","CRLF");
   console.log(data);
```